# Git finds changes because of encoding difference

Tags: java, git, utf-8

I have cloned a java project from a git repository. After opening the project in Eclipse and making some changes, I noticed that git was finding changes in parts of the code that I didn't change. The code looked unchanged on Eclipse so I opened one of the files with Notepad++ where it looks like below if the chosen encoding is UTF-8 (default).

[image: Left: diff of file; Right: file opened on Notepad++ with Encoding UTF-8]

If I change the Notepad++ encoding to ANSI, however, I see the same characters as in the diff.

[image: Left: diff of file; Right: file opened on Notepad++ with Encoding ANSI]

If I overwrite the problematic character in Notepad++ using the ANSI encoding, git doesn't see any changes.

[image: Changed file with ANSI encoding]

I understand that the same two bytes that represent `Ã` and `«` in ANSI probably represent the single character `ë` in UTF-8, but I don't understand how this problem came to be by just cloning the repository and opening the code on Eclipse.

Comment: Welcome to character encoding hell :) Can you reproduce it on a github repo so we can play with it?
I suspect that eclipse did some changes automagically, and that's your problem.